# "About it" versus "about that"

Tags: difference, phrases

Is there any difference *about it* and *about that*, or are both the sentences correct?

> As soon as I see Tom, I will **tell him about that**.

> As soon as I see Tom, I will **tell him about it**.

Comment: Sometimes there is no difference. Sometimes one may be more suitable than the other. It depends on the context.

Comment: It would be useful to get more information and also some examples.

Comment: You might use 'about _that_' if you were pointing to, or otherwise indicating, a physical object that Tom needed to be told about.